# Does $O(n)$ have a proper normal subgroup that contains a reflection?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Here is what I have conjectured.

> Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $O(n)$ (the orthogonal group of an n-dimensional vector space). If there $\exists h\in H,\det h=-1$, then $H=O(n)$.

The cases $n=1,2$ are extremely easy to prove - only some simple algebraic calculations are required. However, I find that this approach doesn't seem to work. I am trying to do an induction on $n$, but this yields no results.

I could not find a counterexample either.

Question: Is the above statement true or false?

Comment: BTW, do you mean that reflection $\iff\det=-1$?

Comment: You're simply using a wrong definition of reflection. With the correct definition the answer is yes for every $n$ because all reflections are conjugate and generate $O(n)$.

Answer (score 3):

It fails for $n=3$. Just take $H=\{\operatorname{Id},-\operatorname{Id}\}$.

Comment: What if I use the correct definition of reflection？

Comment: Yes, but I supposed that you wanted an answer to the question as you have put it.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace $\det h=-1$ with something better matching the word "reflection" in your question title (namely, that $h$ is negative identity in a one-dimensional subspace and the identity on its orthogonal complement), then the claim is true. First note that all such reflections are conjugate (just map the corresponding invariant subspaces to one other), then note that you can map any ON basis to any other ON basis one by one using reflections .